# SqlException: the insert statement is conflicting with the foreign key constraint

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, sqlexception

I am trying to add values to two tables in a database, one which contains the primary key and another purely foreign. I have tried adding to the table with the primary key first followed by the foreign to no avail.

Code on the form to carry out the insert command:

```
int rowsAffected = ProjectDal.AddBookingInfo(GroomOptionComboBox.Text, HairComboBox.Text, TeethComboBox.Text, NailsComboBox.Text, AppointmentDateTimePicker.Text, CustomerStatusComboBox.Text, Convert.ToString(StartingTime), Convert.ToString(FinishTime), Convert.ToString(duration), AllPrice);

if (rowsAffected > 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Booking successfully added", "Success");
    int rowsAffected2 = ProjectDal.AddBooking(Convert.ToInt32(DogIDComboBox.Text), Convert.ToInt32(ClientIDComboBox.Text));

    if (rowsAffected2 > 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Booking successfully added", "Success");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Booking not successful", "Failure");
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Booking not successful", "Failure");
}
```

Code in the ProjectDal:

```
public static int AddBooking(int DogID, int ClientID)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionstring))
    {
        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand insertClientCommand = new SqlCommand();
        insertClientCommand.Connection = connection;
        insertClientCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        insertClientCommand.CommandText = "AddBooking";

        insertClientCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DogID", DogID));
        insertClientCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ClientID", ClientID));

        int rowsAffected = insertClientCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        connection.Close();

        return rowsAffected;
    }
}

public static int AddBookingInfo(string GroomOption, string Hair, string Teeth, string Nails, string DateOfAppointment, string IsFirstTime, string StartTime, string FinishTime, string Duration, double Price)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionstring))
    {
        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand insertClientCommand = new SqlCommand();
        insertClientCommand.Connection = connection;
        insertClientCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        insertClientCommand.CommandText = "AddBookingInfo";

        insertClientCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@GroomOption", GroomOption));
        insertClientCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Hair", Hair));
        insertClientCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Teeth", Teeth));
        insertClientCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Nails", Nails));
        insertClientCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DateOfAppointment", DateOfAppointment));
        insertClientCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@IsFirstTime", IsFirstTime));
        insertClientCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@StartTime",StartTime));
        insertClientCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FinishTime", FinishTime));
        insertClientCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Duration", Duration));
        insertClientCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Price", Price));

        int rowsAffected = insertClientCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        connection.Close();

        return rowsAffected;
    }
}
```

The SQL for both tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BookingInfo] 
(
    [BookingID]         INT IDENTITY (101, 1) NOT NULL,
    [GroomOption]       NCHAR(10)    NULL,
    [Hair]              NCHAR(10)    NULL,
    [Teeth]             NCHAR(10)    NULL,
    [Nails]             NCHAR(10)    NULL,
    [DateOfAppointment] NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [IsFirstTime]       NCHAR(10)    NULL,
    [StartTime]         NCHAR(10)    NULL,
    [FinishTime]        NCHAR(10)    NULL,
    [Duration]          NCHAR(10)    NULL,
    [Price]             FLOAT(53)    NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([BookingID] ASC)
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Booking] 
(
    [BookingID] INT IDENTITY (101, 1) NOT NULL,
    [DogID]     INT NOT NULL,
    [ClientID]  INT NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([BookingID] ASC),

    CONSTRAINT [FK_Booking_ToDogInfo] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([DogID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[DogInfo] ([DogID]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Booking_ToOwner] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([ClientID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Owner] ([ClientID]), 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Booking_ToBookingInfo] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([BookingID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[BookingInfo]([BookingID])
)
```

Comment: From where you are calling AddBooking()? As per your code I think you have to call AddBooking() first and pass BookingID to AddBookingInfo().

Comment: Rel - Don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/) - which is what your parameter creation approach effectively does.

Comment: BookingInfo has an identity column (and is poorly defined but that's a different set of issues). You did not post the AddBookingInfo stored procedure - but how does it return the value of the newly inserted row to your application? And where in your application code to you capture that ID and then pass it along for use in adding the Booking row?

Comment: And now that i look more, you have issues with using identity columns in both tables. Seems you have some confusion over how to design your tables. You cannot have (or expect) two independent identity columns to have the same (i.e, synchronized) values generated and use one as a foreign key to another. As you have currently structured your table, Booking.BookingID cannot be an identity column - it is the FK to BookingInfo and it must be populated by your application.

Answer (score 0):

**You have a number of problems with your code:**

- `BookingID` on the `Booking` table should not be an `IDENTITY` column, nor should it be a primary key (at least not by itself), as it just accepts a foreign key from `BookingInfo`. You may want to make it a primary key with another column.
- Therefore you need to return the ID from the `BookingInfo` insert, to then pass through to the other insert.

**Other notes:**

- Choose your data types carefully: `nchar` is a fixed length and will pad spaces, use `nvarchar` instead for variable-length. Dates should be in `date` or `datetime` columns. Booleans should go in `bit` columns. Anything involving money needs to be in `decimal` not `float`.
- Specify the parameter types, lengths and precision
- Put `SqlCommand` in a `using` block

**Your SQL code would then look something like this:**

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE AddBookingInfo
    @GroomOption NCHAR(10)
.....
    @BookingInfoID int OUTPUT
AS

INSERT BookingInfo
      (GroomOption,....)
VALUES (@GroomOption,...);

SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS int);

GO
```

**Your C# side would look something like this:**

```cs
public static int AddBookingInfo(string GroomOption, string Hair, string Teeth, string Nails, string DateOfAppointment, string IsFirstTime, string StartTime, string FinishTime, string Duration, double Price)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionstring))
    using (SqlCommand insertClientCommand = new SqlCommand("AddBookingInfo", connection))
    {
        insertClientCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        insertClientCommand.Parameters.Add("@GroomOption", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = GroomOption;
        // ......... etc

        connection.Open();
        return (int)insertClientCommand.ExecuteScalar();  // the result is the ID
    }
}

public static int AddBooking(int BookingInfoId, int DogID, int ClientID)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionstring))
    using (SqlCommand insertClientCommand = new SqlCommand("AddBooking", connection))
    {
        insertClientCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        insertClientCommand.Parameters.Add("@BookingInfoID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = BookingInfoId;
        insertClientCommand.Parameters.Add("@DogID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DogID;
        insertClientCommand.Parameters.Add("@ClientID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ClientID;

        connection.Open();
        int rowsAffected = insertClientCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        connection.Close();

        return rowsAffected;
    }
}
```

---

To be honest, your data model appears somewhat suspect: what is the difference between a `Booking` and a `BookingInfo`, do they represent different concepts or should they be in the same table?

Also, `Duration` should be a computed column, because it can be calculated from the other columns, and you shouldn't declare columns as `NULL` when you actually want data to be there.